# Server is not responding to post request when client url is http://localhost:4200

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am writing an Angular app which communicates with Express server. I am stuck in an extraordinary weird problem since last few days, which is as follows:

I am making a post request to the server when the web page is loaded by the user. There are two cases:

1. If URL at the time of reloading is: `http://localhost:4200`. I will programmatically change URL to `http://localhost:4200/allresults?query=`. And make a post request at `http://localhost:3000/allresults` with payload as `criteriaObj={query:'cat'}`
2. If URL at the time of reloading is: `http://localhost:4200/allresults?query=`. I will make a post request at `http://localhost:3000/allresults` with payload as `criteriaObj={query:'cat'}`

Now the problem is: **In the first case, the server does not respond. While in second cases server returns response as expected**

**It is important to note that nature and payload of the post request in both the cases are identical.**

**Video(because how unbelievable it is):**

The following is the 50 sec video recording on youtube. In this video I use breakpoints in chrome to show that callback of Http.subscrible() is not running in the first case, while it's running fine in second case
https://youtu.be/F_tpnm9JoY0

---

**Additional details**:

**Chrome console:**

1. In case 1: `XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "http://localhost:3000/allresults".`
2. In case 2: `XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "http://localhost:3000/allresults".` and `XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/allresults"`.

[image]

In server, I am getting:

1.In case 1: `OPTIONS /allresults`

2.In case 2: `OPTIONS /allresults` and `POST /allresults`

Angular code to make server request:

```
/*Following code sends criteriaObj to server
* Also following code is INDEPENDENT OF HOW WE REACHED HERE
* */

criteriaObj = {searchQuery:"cat"};
this.subscriptionPost = this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/allresults', criteriaObj)
  .map((response: any) => response.json())
  .catch((err: Response) => Observable.throw(err.json()))
  .subscribe(
  /*following callback is NOT called when url at the time host was http://localhost:4200*/

  (value:any) =>{
     this.global.resultsArray = value;
  },

  (error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  }

);
```

In express code I have CORS enables using this code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});
```

I will appreciate any help/suggestion to debug this.

Comment: "the URL at the time of reloading is" makes no sense in this context. If you have a server issue you have exactly one URL and one request. You are mixing things up in strange ways. Debug **the server** and see what arrives.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time to make it as objective as I can and reduce the problem to the angular code that I have posted. That angular code is independent of how it is called. If such code is called twice, and it behaves differently in one case, it to me, is a little weird.  Therefore, I think, whats going on in my head is immaterial. Because of the nature of that code, it should produce the same outcome in both cases.

Comment: In server I am getting OPTIONS /allresults in first case. And  OPTIONS /allresults and POST /allresults in second case, just like the chrome console.

Comment: If the server sends different results it's either because of a) internal state or b) it receives different data. As I said, debug **the server**. The server does not care - does not know - what URL the client has in the URL bar. The server gets a request and sends a response. It has no clue about anything going on on the client apart from those requests. If something is weird it's always the model of reality in the human head that's weird, not the computer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found it finally and it was one hell of a bug. It's very interesting.

In summary, the component which was making post request was getting destroyed by the time response comes from the server and was being replaced by another similar component (not visible with the naked eye). Also, in ngOnDestroy hook, I had unsubscribed from the post request, which made it seem that server is not responding.